# Presence or absence

Tags: word-order

This may really be nitpicking... but how would you best phrase this sentence (the context is a scientific paper)?

> *[parameter]* was measured in the presence or absence of *[drug name]*.

or rather

> *[parameter]* was measured in the absence or presence of *[drug name]*.

The first one sounds better to me, but I cannot say why, nor I would say the second is wrong...

**EDIT**: to better clarify, I have control experiments where the parameter was measured without drug and other experiments where it was measured in its presence.

Comment: Related question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/561260/common-word-for-presence-and-absence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally feel using "presence or absence" gives it a positive connotation followed by the negative one -

in the manner of saying "plus or minus" or "+/-"

In your example, does it mean that the [parameter] was measured in both presence and absence of [drug name] - i.e. twice?

If not it would depend on which is more relevant for the point you're proving - i.e. does the presence of [drug] matter more than the absence?

It seems to be 2 different opposing results to me, but that could be my lack of pharmaceutical context.

**Edit:**

As per your edit, the context has changed.

You actually have two separate tests, so IMHO it should be "was tested in the presence **and** absence of".

To use "or", the sentence should be re-written as "The presence or absence of [drug] does not affect the test [parameter]"

Comment: Compare also "up and down", "rich and poor". On the other hand "in sickness or in health", so the rule is not universal.

Comment: @Colin Fine: "in sickness.." is probably the priest accentuating the negative, giving you a last chance to escape capital punishment while you can.

Comment: You make a good point. I edited my question so that it is (hopefully) more clear. The parameter was measured in both cases (with or without drug) but -for technical reasons- not in the same experiments.

Comment: @nico: as per your edit, it changes the context. You actually have **two separate** tests, so IMHO it should be "in presence **and** absence of", not *or*

Comment: @Colin, "in sickness and in health" is the more common phrasing, not "in sickness or in health."

Answer (score 2):

Why not simplify it by using "with and without [drug name]" .. and it should be "presence and absence", not "or", unless you tested randomly.

Comment: I'm not sure about the use of `and`, although probably `with or without` would do. See edit to my question, the experiments were separate so it's either with or without drug.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that *[parameter]* was measured twice; once in the presence of *[drug]* and once in the absence of *[drug]*?

Or do you mean that it was measured without regard to the presence of *[drug]*?