# Common word for "presence" and "absence"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a common word, describing two other words. For example, if the words I had was "young" and "old", the common word I'm looking for might be "age". If I had "female" and "male", the common word would be "gender". If I had "warm" and "cold", it might be "temperature".

So my question is, what is the common word for "presence" and "absence", in the context of objects?

Comment: Bonus question, purely out of curiosity: is there a special term for such common words?

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hypernym

Comment: **Existence**...

Comment: It gets difficult to analyse all the various cases, but with an easy concrete example like 'cutlery' = 'knives' + 'forks' + 'spoons' + 'sporks' etc, 'cutlery' is the hypernym, and 'knives', forks', 'spoons', 'sporks' etc are 'hyponyms'.

Comment: And you could do “kitchenware,” and throe in not only the cutlery but the pots and pans, the electric mixer, the olive pitter, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler)...

> "Normally ***presence*** is the name of the category, with the values of present or absent. Many binary qualities are named for the unmarked (usually affirmative) case, like length for long/short."

Answer (score 0):

I believe *attendance* is the word you're looking for.

The [definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/attendance) is 'the person or numbers of persons present,' which could also cover how many people are absent.

If I ask whether Bob is present or absent, it would be a question in terms of his attendance. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just clarified the question to point out that the context is not that of people, but of objects. Otherwise, your answer would be perfect.